# Android Button Padding Not Respected on Device

Tags: android, padding

I'm a little stumped on this one - when I play with the padding with the emulator, it displays as I'd expect. However when I run the app on the actual device it appears that the padding on the buttons have no effect whatsoever.

I can change the button text and that displays, but the padding seems to have no effect on the device.

I've tried removing the padding entirely as well as setting it to 125dp, and nothing changes. I'm probably missing something dumb. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Here's my layout - the two buttons at the bottom are where padding isn't respected (it works fine in the `LinearLayouts`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".LocationActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">

    <ImageView
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New survey available!"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="It should take a minute or less."/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Answer Survey"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="23 hours 38 minutes remaining"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$14.59"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Google Play credit"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:textColor="#0266C8"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
    android:text="Spend your play credit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" />

<Button
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:textColor="#0266C8"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="Reward history"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" />
```

Comment: Do you have another screen-specific layout directory ? Something like `/layout-w600dp` (normally for tablet) in addition to `/layout` ? If nothing changes then the app you see on the device might not be using the layout you edited.

Comment: I don't. I included the full layout if you want to check it out.

Comment: If you change the text, does it reflect on the device?  That would be a good clue if you are modifying the correct layout.

Comment: Yes, it does. Just not the padding